# How to modify a dataframe with conditions for each name duplicated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is data that indicates whether a single person has capitalizable and non-capitalizable contracts. I want to have it grouped by names and create a new column that tells me if he/she has both contracts and the sum of all contracts. (its a pretty big one)

| id | name | Capitalization | number of contracts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jimmy | yes | 3 |
| 1 | Jimmy | no | 1 |
| 2 | Jenny | no | 7 |
| 3 | Elle | yes | 5 |
| 4 | Danny | yes | 2 |
| 5 | Charles | yes | 1 |
| 6 | Freddy | no | 3 |
| 7 | Elle | yes | 5 |
| 7 | Elle | no | 3 |

The final result would look like this:

| id | name | Capitalization_x | number of contracts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jimmy | both | 4 |
| 2 | Jenny | no | 7 |
| 3 | Elle | yes | 5 |
| 4 | Danny | yes | 2 |
| 5 | Charles | yes | 1 |
| 6 | Freddy | no | 3 |
| 7 | Elle | both | 8 |

I am really stuck with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using aggregation:

```
(df.groupby('id').agg({'Capitalization': lambda s: 'both' if len(set(s))==2 else s, 
                       'number of contracts': 'sum',
                       'name': 'first'}))
```

Here, I assume the only possible values in `Capitalization` are `"yes"` or `"no"`. Let me know if otherwise.

You can always change the logic in the lambda function to accommodate more complex cases.

---

```
       name Capitalization  number of contracts
id                                             
1     Jimmy           both                    4
2     Jenny             no                    7
3      Elle            yes                    5
4     Danny            yes                    2
5   Charles            yes                    1
6    Freddy             no                    3
7      Elle           both                    8
```

Comment: Yes, Capitalization only has these two values. Thank you very much. That's what I needed.

Comment: `df.groupby(['id', 'name'], as_index=False).agg({'Capitalization': lambda s: 'both' if len(set(s))==2 else s, 'number of contracts': 'sum'})` may be a slightly simpler version~